# Which professors are involved in the tenure decision (in USA)? (associate, full, tenure-track who becomes tenured before I get tenure etc...)

Tags: united-states, tenure-track

Which professors are involved in the tenure decision? Is it all tenured professors, or also the one still on tenure-track? If only tenured, which is the date in which they get tenure that matters? For example, I am in my second year of tenure-track position, will a person who is in his/her third year of tenure-track position have a word about my case? Basically, there is person I am doing all my best to get along with, but on his/her side it is just not happening. I have great relationship with most people, but this person just doesn't like me. I tried so hard to talk with this person and makes things right. In which cases will this person have a word to say?

Comment: This is why decisions are by majority vote, rather than unanimous vote.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, or, anyway, super-majority vote.

Comment: The answer will be in your faculty manual.

Comment: This depends on your institution’s policies, you’ll need to ask at your department what the rules are. I voted to close as unanswerable for that reason. Good luck with your tenure case at any rate.

Answer (score 5):

You should ask your department chair, as practices can vary.

Usually, all promotion decisions are voted on by faculty who have already received the promotion.  So for tenure, only tenured faculty will vote.

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S., it seems that only already-tenured faculty vote on the tenure-or-not of tenure-track faculty.

But/and if the person you don't get along with gains tenure a year before you do, yes, they could vote on your case.

But, still, approval for tenure (at the department level) does not require unanimity, only some sort of super-majority, perhaps 2/3.

Comment: And it may be only the votes of a committee, not all of the tenured faculty. And normally the administration can still not grant tenure after a favorable decision for some defined reasons, such as financial.

Comment: There are exceptions to everything, of course.  In my department, assistant professors are allowed to vote on tenure cases (though they often abstain), and the decision is more or less by simple majority.

Comment: @NateEldredge, hm, I am surprised. Not that I think it's a bad idea, considering the greater potential corruptibility of requiring substantial super-majorities (which allows more potential "blackballing" by small-but-vocal cliques).

Comment: @NateEldredge: That's interesting.  At my university only people with tenure can vote on tenure (and only associate and full professors can vote on promotion to associate professor, etc.), and abstentions are recorded and count essentially as negative votes.

Answer (score 2):

Echoing others, you should consult your faculty manual as every university tends to be a bit different. At most universities it is just tenured faculty who vote on tenure cases, and often a constituted committee (at our university, we elect our departmental committees from the tenured ranks; we want a majority of full professors but a few associates can serve).

That said, your department chair (or whoever chairs your departmental tenure and promotion committee) and the dean of your school/faculty, or whoever chairs the next-level tenure and promotion committee, will be attentive to these sorts of dynamics. Tenure cases and votes are products of careful consideration, both by committees as well as by your external letters. I have sat on tenure and promotion committees (in Canada, but our system is basically the same as the American one), and I would like to think that interpersonal dynamics don't play a significant role; we are professionals, engaging with each other and our colleagues as professionals.

If it is a *serious* conflict, where you are worried about this individual's ability to render an impartial decision, you should talk to your chair or faculty association. Most universities should have some sort of procedure to remove people due to conflicts of interest.